# Send data through a POST request from Angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in the controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('TaskController', function ($scope, TaskFactory) {
    $scope.addTodo = function () {
      $scope.todos.push({text : $scope.formTodoText});
      $scope.formTodoText = '';
    };
  });
```

and this in the factory

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('TaskFactory', function ($q, $http) {
    var sendTasks = function(params) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      console.log(1, params);
      $http.post('http://localhost:3000/task/save', params)
        .success(function(data) {
          console.log(2);
          console.log('data', data);
        })
        .error(function(err) {
          defer.reject(err);
        });
      return defer.promise;
    }

    return {
      sendTask: function(taskData) {
        console.log('taskData', taskData);
        return sendTasks('/task/save', {
          taskData : taskData
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

all I need is to know, how to send the data from the controller to the factory in order to do the POST to the specified route ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the function/method inside factory with the required params.

```js
 angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('TaskController', function ($scope, TaskFactory) {
    $scope.addTodo = function () {
      $scope.todos.push({text : $scope.formTodoText});
      TaskFactory.sendTask({data : $scope.formTodoText})
      $scope.formTodoText = '';
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

[You can follow Dan Wahlin blog post.](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service)

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('customersApp')
    .controller('customersController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', function ($scope, dataFactory) {

    $scope.status; 

    dataFactory.updateCustomer(cust)
      .success(function () {
          $scope.status = 'Updated Customer! Refreshing customer list.';
      })
      .error(function (error) {
          $scope.status = 'Unable to update customer: ' + error.message;
      });    
}
```

**Factory:**

```
angular.module('customersApp')
    .factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

    var urlBase = '/api/customers';   

    dataFactory.updateCustomer = function (cust) {
        return $http.put(urlBase + '/' + cust.ID, cust)
    };

}
```

Hope that solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function directly on the TaskFactory that you pass into the controller as a dependency.

I've cleaned up your code a bit and created [a plunk for you here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GsTBEN?p=preview):

And here's the code:

**Controller**

```
(function(angular) {

    // Initialise our app
    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('TaskController', function($scope, TaskFactory) {

      // Initialise our variables
      $scope.todos = [];
      $scope.formTodoText = '';

      $scope.addTodo = function() {
        // Add an object to our array with a 'text' property
        $scope.todos.push({
          text: $scope.formTodoText
        });

        // Clear the input
        $scope.formTodoText = '';

        // Call function to send all tasks to our endpoint
        $scope.sendTodos = function(){
          TaskFactory.sendTasks($scope.todos);
        }
      };
  });

})(angular);
```

**Factory**

```
(function(angular) {

    angular.module('myApp')
        .factory('TaskFactory', function($q, $http) {

            var sendTasks = function(params) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $http.post('http://localhost:3000/task/save', params)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        console.log('data: ' + data);
                    })
                    .error(function(err) {
                        defer.reject(err);
                    });
                return defer.promise;
            }

            return {
                sendTasks: sendTasks
            }

        });

})(angular);
```